# "Нерискованный" или "не рискованный"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

"Нерискованный" или "не рискованный"?

В контексте "Любители нерискованных игр"

Comment: Думаю, в сочетании с играми правильнее "безрисковые".

Answer (score 1):

Формально говоря, слово *нерискованный* в данном случае должно писаться слитно.
Вот похожий пример.

> В делах большого хозяйства и в этом и в других имениях он держался самых простых, **нерискованных** приемов и был в высшей степени бережлив и расчетлив на хозяйственные мелочи. [Л. Н. Толстой. Анна Каренина (1878)]

Однако по смыслу оно тут вряд ли подходит. Как отметил Alex_ander, тут кажется уместнее слово "безрисковый". Давайте сравним *безрисковый* и *нерискованный*.

> **Безрисковые** инвестиции – англ. Risk-Free Investments, являются условным понятием, подразумевающим инвестиции, по которым вероятность получения убытка инвестором равна нолю. Осуществление безрисковых инвестиций предполагает, что инвестор, по крайней мере, не потеряет свои вложения, или даже получит определенный доход.

Аналогично **безрисковые** игры — игры, в которых вероятность проигрыша (убытка) равна нолю.

> Не все геймеры предпочитают рисковать, многие выбирают безрисковые игры, и наслаждаются игровым процессом без финансового риска.

**Рискованная** игра — игра, связанная с риском, с опасностью, часто употребляется в переносном смысле, когда говорят об авантюре.

> После поражения от болгар вплоть до матча с Грузией я настраивал команду по-прежнему бороться только за первое место. Требовал в каждом матче стремиться к максимально возможному результату. Пусть гонка за лидером и не удастся ― хотелось, чтобы разрыв между нами и украинцами на финише был как можно меньше. Разрешил всем идти на **рискованную** игру даже черным цветом.
>   [Денис Драгунский. Пространство и бремя // «Частный корреспондент», 2010]
>
> Осенью мальчишки играли в довольно **рискованную** игру ― перебегали улицу перед извозчиками. [Николай Тихонов. На всю жизнь... // «Огонек». № 27, 1959]

Что же тогда означает словосочетание *нерискованная игра* (кстати, его не удалось найти в Нацкорпусе русского языка)? Думаю, это игра с минимальным риском. Это скорее не о типе игры, а об игровой манере, тактике. Например, футбольная команда уходит в глухую оборону, шахматист с самого начала ведет партию к ничьей. Вы о любителях таких игр? Тогда пишите: "Любители нерискованных игр".

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу оснований для раздельного написания - нет ни противопоставления, ни пояснительных слов. Пишите слитно.

Comment: Синонимичных, видимо.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, речь идет об играх без риска, и тогда это **виртуальные игры,** а  безрИсковая игра ― это термин (риск в это случае действительно полностью отсутствует).

Например http://www.baraholkin.ru/igra-bez-riska-vozmozhno-li-eto/

"Это игра в удовольствие и без какого-либо риска. От вас не потребуют регистрации, платной смс или открытия депозитного счета, так что возможность потери ваших кровных сведена к нулю. Но это еще не все преимущества, отметим некоторые из них отдельно:

-изучение всех тонкостей конкретного слота, что в дальнейшем позволит более уверенно и обдуманно делать реальные ставки;

-безопасное тестирование новых стратегий и тактик в игре"; И т.д.

Прилагательное ***нерискованный*** используется крайне редко, более употребительным и точным по значению является слово ***малорискованный***. Поэтому обычно при наличии частицы НЕ мы имее отрицательные конструкции, например:

...не полезет Ягайло в бой, цель его похода ― грабеж русских земель, а **не рискованная** схватка с войском князя московского. [Андрей Надиров.  1977]

...это задача хотя и **не рискованная,** но, во всяком случае, требующая некоторого мастерства. [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Наша общественная жизнь (1863-1864)]

А **не рискованный** трюк? ― спросил он. [Олег Дивов. (1998)]

Comment: В Нацкорпусе есть несколько (очень мало) вхождений как слова *нерискованный*, так и слова *малорискованный*.